# One-row textarea in Firefox refuses to show vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, firefox, textarea

I've already figured out that Firefox's sizing of textareas is buggy - it always adds one to your rows and cols settings. But I've decided to just ignore that. The problem is that Firefox also refuses to put in the vertical scrollbar, even if I type a friggin' short story into the box.

Am I doing something wrong (i.e. invalid)? Is there a workaround?

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="35" name="Cmnt1"></textarea>
```

(I want to use a one-row textarea instead of an input type=text precisely because the latter doesn't provide scrollbars. All the other browsers will give you a vertical scrollbar even on a one-row textarea.)

Note that this field will almost always contain just a single line of text, but it needs to accept more "just in case". A text input field is less than satisfactory (<-- understatement) because it *always* hides the overflow. In every other browser, a single-row textarea works exactly as I want. I vehemently disagree that what I want is a usability problem. Unfortunately, the way it behaves in Firefox *is* a usability problem.

Edit: turns out there's a bug with my installation of Firefox. :/

Comment: This sounds like a usability nightmare. What is your reasoning other than that you "want" it?

Comment: Can you link to a live example of this behavior? I can't replicate it myself.

Comment: Use css properties height and width for accurate sizing of textareas. Keep the rows/cols as a fallback.

Comment: Why on earth do you think this is a usability nightmare? (Well, in Firefox it is, but that's hardly my fault.) What would you have me do instead?

Comment: @Martha: Having a multi-line text field display only one row makes is very difficult to edit or even see the text entered. This results in a bad user-experience. If you want users not to enter more text then you should use a single-line text field, otherwise display at least 3 rows (Many usability guidelines consider this value the absolute minimum). Just to give an example, the field to enter this comment displays 4 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is really old, but I have a similar issue and found the answer to your question in the process. Playing with a jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/z8btg/1/ ) in firefox revealed that the vertical scrollbar is only visible if there is room to display both the up and down arrow graphics. (Click on the little resize icon and make it small / big.) For me, the sweet spot is **34** pixels.

What I am trying to do:
I need the textarea to be one line until the textarea is focused, then I change it to a larger (popout style) textarea.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the *overflow* css property to "scroll". For example:

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="35" name="Cmnt1" style="overflow: scroll;"></textarea>
```

**Edit:** Sorry, should be `overflow-y: scroll`.

Comment: This doesn't help. Neither does "overflow:auto". "Scroll" will make the horizontal scrollbar appear at all times, and "auto" has no effect. Neither setting will make the <i>vertical</i> scrollbar appear.

Comment: What about "overflow-y:scroll"?

Comment: It seems I'm not the only one seeing different behavior than you are. "It works perfectly for me, pasting or typing manually. – Tyler Rash"

Using "overflow-y:scroll" causes a vertical and only a vertical scrollbar to show up in the textarea at all times in my browser unless I set the height manually with CSS. I'm not sure what the difference is between our browsers, but I do not appreciate your "less polite" comments.

Comment: Ok, it seems that the problem is with my particular installation of Firefox. I just installed FF on a different computer, and got lovely vertical scrollbars. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on the textarea, hit the return key.

This sounds like a pretty terrible idea, by the way.

Comment: What sounds like a terrible idea? And hitting return doesn't help - like I said, you can type (or rather, copy & paste) an entire short story into the box, Firefox will still refuse to show a vertical scrollbar. (If you type a very long word, it'll show the horizontal scrollbar, but still no vertical one.)

Comment: Are you saying that in Firefox, you have a textarea with rows=1, and you get a *vertical* scrollbar? What version of Firefox??

Answer (score 1):

I used something like this to present a html link to visitors, needed to fit into the design and usability is just fine for it's intended function:

<input type="text" name="linkHTML" id="linkHTML" style="width: 95%;" value='YOUR TEXT CONTENT' onfocus="this.select()" onclick="this.select()" />

Set width as needed (% or px).

On click will highlight for copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the textarea to `1em` with CSS (which means one line-height unit) and set the rows to a higher value.

Comment: That doesn't work, or rather it results in exactly the same behavior as using rows="1". I just tried it, and the vertical scrollbars do not appear at any height setting below 2.7em.

Comment: Interesting - I would guess that is your answer. If you think this is a FF bug, do report it to them so they know about it. 

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

I am using Firefox 2.0.  The scrollbar on the textarea does not show up until the height of the textarea is 32px (which is about two lines of text).  If the height is less than that the scrollbars disappear -- probably because there is not enough room to show the arrow icons.